# Effect of expansion on time?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, reference-frames, universe, space-expansion

We know that for moving body times moves at a slower rate, but can this happen for Universe itself whose rate of expansion is accelerating?

Comment: are you asking if time slows down due to the acceleration of the universe's expansion?

Answer (score 2):

> We know that for moving body times moves at a slower rate

Motion is relative.  If Alice and Bob are in relative uniform motion, Alice observes Bob's clock to run slow while Bob observes Alice's clock to run slow.  But neither Bob nor Alice can perceive their own clock running slow.

> but can this happen for Universe itself whose rate of expansion is
>   accelerating

Assuming there is a Universal clock, to what other clock would it be compared?

Answer (score 2):

I like Alfred's answer, it's simple and easy to understand if you don't have a background in GR. However, for those of you with a background in GR, you might say that we would be able to tell if the accelerated expansion had an effect on time because of how it is coded into the metric. So let me present a more formal answer.

The accelerated expansion of the universe does not have any effect on the flow rate of time. Let me write down the equation that describes the entire geometry of the universe and everything in it; the perturbed FLRW-metric:

$$ds^2=a^2(\tau)\left[-(1+2A)d\tau^2-2B,_{i}d\tau\,dx^i+\left[(1-2\zeta)\delta_{ij}+E,_{ij}\right]dx^idx^j\right]$$

Where A, B, E, and $\zeta$ are perturbations (matter, radiation, etc), $\tau$ is conformal time (a meaningless quantity for practical applications) and $x$ is comoving length. The flow of time is (more or less) regulated by the terms with $d\tau$. The factor $a^2(\tau)$ out in front is the scale factor and that represents the expansion of the universe. Now, since there is one $a(\tau)$ factor multiplying each $d\tau$ in the equation, you might think that the flow of time is affected by the expansion. However, conformal time, $\tau$ has almost no relation to how much time passes for the universe. It is instead a measure of how long it takes light to travel a certain distance if the universe were the size it is today and not expanding (not a physically meaningful measurement but it's useful in other parts of cosmology). The time we all know and love, the one that is a meaningful measurement, is the proper time (usually denoted $t$). The proper time is found as $t=a(\tau)\tau$, which means that when you plug this into the metric to find the terms that govern the flow of time, you find two terms:

1) $-(1+2A)dt^2$: this term, you'll note, includes density perturbations (meaning time is influenced by gravity) but no scale factor (meaning it doesn't have time being influenced by the expansion).

2) $-2a(\tau)B,_idt\,dx^i$: As I mentioned, $x$ is comoving length. This is not the length measured on a ruler, which is the proper length. Proper length is found as $a(\tau)x$. Thus, this term describes how time interacts with the change in space of density perturbations; that is, this term contributes (contributes being the key word) to how velocity of an object affects the flow of time around it.

You'll notice that, other than the physically meaningless conformal time, there are no terms describing the interaction between the expansion of space and time. Thus, neither the expansion of space nor the acceleration of that expansion changes the flow of proper time.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need much special knowledge to understand the answer to this question.

Start with asking yourself: How would I know that time in the whole universe was slowed down by a universal factor?

Would you take out your stopwatch and measure if the universe runs at a different rate? But universal slowing down means that your stopwatch also slows down and you cannot tell the difference. If every physical law and every physical phenomenon would apply with a slower rate, how could one tell?

The answer is one could not. When physics talks about time it talks about a time up to a universal "rate factor" for the whole universe. The only thing physics can measure is relative duration of different processes.

Relativity is pushing this concept a bit further by stating that different observers at different speeds will measure the relative duration of processes with different results. Furthermore, if they accelerate and meet after a certain time, they may find that some of them have aged less and some more - for some, "more physics happened" and for others less. This is the precise meaning of time "slowing down" and "getting faster" - it only make sense in comparison to a rate of time of another process.

By definition, time slowing down or running faster for the whole universe does not make sense since there is nothing with respect to which it would be slowing down or running faster.

Answer (score 0):

The answer must refer to the **clock of space expansion**. Space is expanding with time, i.e. every second space is expanding by a certain percentage, the unit of the Hubble constant being 1/sec. By consequence, the expanding universe is a clock, its acceleration is secondary (however, acceleration of this clock must be taken into account for synchronization).

A comoving frame (for example the frame of a planet) for which space expansion is isotropic in every direction can be used as reference frame. The reference frame of this planet has a proper time.  Observers near the planet which are moving with respect to this planet are measuring a coordinate time which is dilated with respect to the proper time of the planet, due to time dilation.

The story becomes a bit more complicated when we are considering observers which are not near to the planet of reference. Remote observers may be in a frame which is comoving with space expansion, but due to space expansion they are also in motion with respect to the observed comoving planet. By consequence, if we want to measure time dilation of an observer with regard to space expansion we must always refer to a (fictitious) comoving planet which is located near the observer.

Comment: This answer implies that we can calculate the time dilation of receding comoving objects by simply using the recessional velocity in the standard SR way. This is not the case and is evidenced by the fact that if we were to receive light from something near the edge of the observable universe now, that object would have always had a recessional velocity greater than c during the time the light was travelling to us

Comment: You did not understand the nature of space expansion. The second postulate (velocity limit c) is not violated. --- In the last paragraph I show that application of special relativity is restricted: time dilation must be measured locally. --- I agree that SR is partially rectified by GR, but we have to analyze in each case if and how the application of SR is restricted.